# MS Access Barcode Scanning

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

New to MS Access and was curious if there is a way to tell if a barcode that is scanned is either a FedEx barcode or a UPS barcode. From what I've seen, UPS has alpha numeric barcodes and FedEx has 12 digit numeric barcodes. I'm sure this varies.

I would like to add another column to the table called "Type_TrackNum" that will store whether the label is FedEx or UPS. I would like for this to be attached to the CurrentDB.Execute command.

Here is what I have so far, this also cuts off the leading zeros whenever there are leading zeros, typically found in FedEx barcodes.

```
Dim strIn As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim iLen As Integer

strIn = Me.txt_Track.Value
iLen = Len(strIn)

For i = 1 To iLen
    If InStr(strIn, "0") = 1 Then
        strIn = Mid(strIn, 2)
    End If
Next i

CurrentDb.Execute _
    "INSERT INTO TrackNum_Table(TrackingNum_TrackNum) " & _
    "VALUES ('" & strIn & "')"
```

Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: Does the code do what you want? If not, what happens - error message, wrong results, nothing? I have no idea if the bar code source can be determined by its structure.

Comment: Is there any way to say... if the scanned barcode is alphanumeric, then it is ups, if numeric, then fedex

Comment: A way could be easily be coded to say 'if this is numeric then it's fedex', or vice versa. The problem is, an alphanumeric code *could* come out as all numbers, so there's no guarantee that it would be given the right category (ups or fedex).

Comment: Only if it is a certainly that UPS always has at least one alpha and FedEx never does.

Comment: @wazz If UPS would be a random alphanumeric barcode of 12 characters without any special characters or capitalization, the chance of it being a valid integer = (10/36)^12 = 2.11*10^-18.  If you're working with less than a billion codes, I'd say that's an acceptable risk. If you're working with more, you likely shouldn't be using Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
Dim strIn As String
Dim strType As String 'NEW
Dim i As Integer
Dim iLen As Integer

strIn = Me.txt_Track.Value
iLen = Len(strIn)

If IsNumeric(strIn) Then
    strType = "FedEx"

    For i = 1 To iLen
        If Left(strIn, 1) = "0" Then
            strIn = Mid(strIn, 2)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Else
    strType = "UPS"
End If

CurrentDb.Execute _
    "INSERT INTO TrackNum_Table(TrackingNum_TrackNum, Type_TrackNum) " & _
    "VALUES ('" & strIn & "', '" & strType & "')"
```